# How to download a file after scraping it's href, that has no http or https in it

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How do I download a file after I scape it's href using bs4. I have no problem getting the href but when I try to fetch the file I get errors.

Here is the site:
https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2016/dp-pd/prof/details/download-telecharger/comp/page_dl-tc.cfm?Lang=E

Here is the source HTML that I get the href from:

```
<a href="/census-recensement/2016/dp-pd/prof/details/download- 
telecharger/comp/GetFile.cfm?Lang=E&amp;FILETYPE=CSV&amp;GEONO=059" 
title="Canada, provinces and territories – File format CSV" class="btn 
btn-default btn-block"></a>
```

First attempt: didn't work.

```
for i, r in enumerate(rows):
    file = f'{r.find("th").text}.csv'
    urlretrieve(f'https://{r.find("a")["href"]}', filename=str(filename.joinpath(file)))
```

Second attempt: It didn't work either.

```
for i, r in enumerate(rows):
    href = r.find('a', href=True)
    remote_file = requests.get(href['href'])
    with open(href['href'], 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in remote_file.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`href['href']` will return you `/census-recensement/2016/dp-pd/prof/details/download-telecharger/comp/GetFile.cfm?Lang=E&FILETYPE=CSV&GEONO=059` you have to add `https://www12.statcan.gc.ca` before this.

```
csv_url = "https://www12.statcan.gc.ca" + href['href']
```

To save file try this

```
# replace csv_url with your scraped link
csv_url = 'https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2016/dp-pd/prof/details/download-telecharger/comp/GetFile.cfm?Lang=E&FILETYPE=CSV&GEONO=059'

req = requests.get(csv_url)
url_content = req.content
csv_file = open('downloaded.csv', 'wb')
csv_file.write(url_content)
csv_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem you can add 'https://www12.statcan.gc.ca' prefix to href. After that you will get valid link to file. For file in your example valid link to file is 'https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2016/dp-pd/prof/details/download-telecharger/comp/GetFile.cfm?Lang=E&FILETYPE=CSV&GEONO=059'. If you have clickable button on site which give you ability to download some file, you can do Right click -> Copy link Location and paste it to Notepad or another text editor and look at this link to discover prefix for href.